# Update combobox MVVM (XAML & C#)

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, combobox

I have a form with 2 combos, among other fields. 1 combo is filled with brand names (**cmbMarca**).  This combo is filled correctly.
The other combo (**cmbModelo**) should be filled with models of the selected brand.

My problem is that the combo with models (**cmbModelo**) is not updated when selecting a brand (cmbBrand). When I select a brand, runs all the code but does not display any item in the combo "**cmbModelo**"

**FillingForm.xaml**

```
    <Input:SfComboBox x:Name="cmbMarca"   x:uid="BrandsCombo"
    DisplayMemberPath="marca"
ItemsSource="{Binding MarcasSAT.Marcas}"                                                       SelectedValue="{Binding marca, Mode=TwoWay}"
    SelectedValuePath="marca"     
    Tag="{Binding Path=SelectedMarca, Mode=TwoWay}"                                                     SelectionChanged="cmbMarca_SelectionChanged"/>  

    <Input:SfComboBox x:Name="cmbModelo"    x:uid="ModelosCombo" 
    DisplayMemberPath="modelo"    
    ItemsSource="{Binding ModelosSAT.Modelos}" 
     SelectedValue="{Binding modelo, Mode=TwoWay}"
    SelectedValuePath="modelo" />
```

**FillingForm.CS**

```
  private void cmbMarca_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {            
                MarcaViewModel curItem = (MarcaViewModel)cmbMarca.SelectedItem;               
                this.cmbMarca.Tag  = curItem.idMarca;
        }
```

**FillingViewModel.cs**

```
public class FillingViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

        private readonly MarcasViewModel marcasSAT = new MarcasViewModel();
        public MarcasViewModel MarcasSAT
        {
            get { return this.marcasSAT; }
        }

        private ModelosViewModel modelosSAT = new ModelosViewModel();
        public ModelosViewModel ModelosSAT
        {
            get
            {
                return this.modelosSAT;
            }
            set
            {
                modelosSAT = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ModelosSAT");
            }
        }

        private int _selectedMarca;
        public int SelectedMarca
        {
            get { return _selectedMarca; }
            set 
            {
                _selectedMarca = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedMarca");
                modelosSAT.MarcaID = _selectedMarca;           
            }
        }

}
```

**ModelosViewModel.cs**

```
 public class ModelosViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private ObservableCollection<ModeloViewModel> modelos;
        public ObservableCollection<ModeloViewModel> Modelos
        {
            get
            {
                return modelos ;
            }
            set
            {
                modelos  = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Modelos");
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<ModeloViewModel> GetModelos()
        {
            modelos  = new ObservableCollection<ModeloViewModel>();
            using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(App.DBPath))
            {
                var query = db.Table<Modelos>().Where(c => c.idMarca == _marcaID);   
                //var query = db.Table<Modelos>();   
                foreach (var _mrc in query)
                {
                    var mrc = new ModeloViewModel()
                    {
                        idMarca  = _mrc.idMarca,
                        idModelo = _mrc.idModelo,
                        modelo   = _mrc.modelo                          
                    };
                    modelos.Add(mrc);
                }
            }
            return modelos ;
        }

        private int _marcaID=0;
        public int MarcaID
        {
            get {
                return _marcaID; 
            }
            set
            {
                _marcaID = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("MarcaID");
                this.GetModelos();
            }
        }

        //public ModelosViewModel()
        //{           
        //    this.modelos = GetModelos();
        //}

    }
```

MarcasViewModel.cs

```
 public class MarcasViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private ObservableCollection<MarcaViewModel> marcas;
        public ObservableCollection<MarcaViewModel> Marcas
        {
            get
            {
                return marcas ;
            }

            set
            {
                marcas  = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Marcas");
            }
        }


        public ObservableCollection<MarcaViewModel> GetMarcas()
        {
            marcas = new ObservableCollection<MarcaViewModel>();
            using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(App.DBPath))
            {
                var query = db.Table<Marcas>();
                foreach (var _mrc in query)
                {
                    var mrc = new MarcaViewModel()
                    {
                        idMarca  = _mrc.idMarca ,
                        marca  = _mrc.marca                         
                    };
                    marcas.Add(mrc);
                }
            }
            return marcas ;
        }

        public MarcasViewModel()
        {
            this.marcas = GetMarcas();
        }

    }
```

**ViewModelBase.cs**

```
 public class ViewModelBase
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

    }
```

UPDATE1:

when I select a brand item, only the next code is called and in this order:

**1st (in FillinfgForm.cs)**

```
 private void cmbMarca_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {            
                MarcaViewModel curItem = (MarcaViewModel)cmbMarca.SelectedItem;        
                this.cmbMarca.Tag  = curItem.idMarca;            
        }
```

**2nd  (in FillingViewModel.cs)**

```
public int SelectedMarca 
  set 
            {
                _selectedMarca = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedMarca");
                modelosSAT.MarcaID = _selectedMarca;           
            }
```

**3rd**    (in ModelosViewModel.cs)

```
Public int MarcaID
    {            
        set
        {
            _marcaID = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("MarcaID");
            this.GetModelos();
        }
    }
```

**4th**

```
public ObservableCollection<ModeloViewModel> GetModelos()
    {
        modelos  = new ObservableCollection<ModeloViewModel>();
        using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(App.DBPath))
        {
            var query = db.Table<Modelos>().Where(c => c.idMarca == _marcaID);   
            //var query = db.Table<Modelos>();   
            foreach (var _mrc in query)
            {
                var mrc = new ModeloViewModel()
                {
                    idMarca  = _mrc.idMarca,
                    idModelo = _mrc.idModelo,
                    modelo   = _mrc.modelo                          
                };
                modelos.Add(mrc);
            }
        }
        return modelos ;
    }
```

Comment: Did you use the debugger? Breakpoints in Setters and gettrs? What gets called? What is not called?

Comment: Don't call lengthly operations in constructor and/or your properties, it blocks your UI thread. Use async commands to start lengthly operation or navigation aware view models (like implemented in Prims) to handle lengthly operations

Comment: @tseng thanks for your comment. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in `GetMarcas()` methods.
As you can see you work not with the property but with the field - 'marcas'. But when you assign a value to a field (in you particular case marcas = new ObservableCollection();) PropertyChanged method is not invoked. That is why you don't see UI changes.
You should work with the property istead of field or you can clear the existing ObservableCollection and add you values. Both variants should work.
So the following code should work:

```
public ObservableCollection<MarcaViewModel> GetMarcas()
{
    Marcas = new ObservableCollection<MarcaViewModel>();
    using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(App.DBPath))
    {
        var query = db.Table<Marcas>();
        foreach (var _mrc in query)
        {
            var mrc = new MarcaViewModel()
            {
                idMarca  = _mrc.idMarca ,
                marca  = _mrc.marca                         
            };
            marcas.Add(mrc);
        }
    }
    return marcas ;
}
```

or, a better solution:

```
public ObservableCollection<MarcaViewModel> GetMarcas()
{
    Marcas.Clear();
    using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(App.DBPath))
    {
        var query = db.Table<Marcas>();
        foreach (var _mrc in query)
        {
            var mrc = new MarcaViewModel()
            {
                idMarca  = _mrc.idMarca ,
                marca  = _mrc.marca                         
            };
            Marcas.Add(mrc);
        }
    }
    return marcas;
}
```

Also there is a good practice called "do not ignore return values", as you can see you don't need to return ObservableCollection from `GetMarcas`, so either rewrite it so that it returns nothing or rewrite invoking code (it dependes on your existing code).

Comment: But GetMarcas() (Brands) runs fine. The combo "cmbMarcas" Is filled correctly. The problem is in the combo: cmbModel (Modelos). I have updated my question.

Comment: the same for models, instead of `modelos  = new ObservableCollection<ModeloViewModel>();` try writing `Modelos.Clear()`

Comment: Alex: I have tried it, but then I am getting this error: An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in nameapp.exe but was not handled in user code. {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

Comment: And if I try your 1st solution, set
            {
                modelos  = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Modelos");
            } is called, but no items displayed in combo "cmbModelo"

Comment: Try changing `private ObservableCollection<ModeloViewModel> modelos;` to `private ObservableCollection<ModeloViewModel> modelos = new ObservableCollecion<ModeloViewModel>();` and using `modelos.Clear()`.

Comment: Thank you!!! :-) You fixed the issue. Now I'll update my other classes because they are also incorrect.